# Javascript: using toLocaleString + Tofixed

Tags: javascript, formatting

I need to format a number for a project im working on at work, only problem is that I cant format it how i want.

I convert the number to a localestring using the `toLocaleString` method which gives me the commas but i also need decimal places, nothing i seem to do works.

```
var number = 123.322
number = parseFloat(number).toFixed(2) //123.22
number.toLocaleString() //123.22
```

The above code just returns the parsefloated number along with the tofixed decimal values but it doesn't add the commas.

How do i get a number to have two decimal places **(when the value is 'xx.00')** and also be comma separated. Is this possible in JavaScript?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can give an object to `.toLocaleString()` which describes what you want:

```
var sNumber = (10123.322).toLocaleString(undefined,
 {'minimumFractionDigits':2,'maximumFractionDigits':2});
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Original:

```js
const fNumber = 10123.322;
const sNumber = parseFloat(fNumber.toFixed(2)).toLocaleString();
console.log(sNumber);
```

The number is already in decimal/float format on the first line.

- `.toFixed(2)` turns it into a string using fixed-point notation.
- `parseFloat()` takes that string and turns it back into a float.
- `.toLocaleString()` turns it into a string using the local format.

Comment: Sweet! This is the cleanest solution!

Comment: this is pure gold

Comment: The `parseFloat()` version doesn't work for me in case my number is an integer; it won't add the decimals. `toLocaleString()` with options is what I needed !

Answer (score 1):

Just to do it in one line

```
var num = '12233.3366554';
num = parseFloat(parseFloat(num).toFixed(2)).toLocaleString('en-IN', { useGrouping: true });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to either the quesitoner's code or anything from any of the answers, except forcing the locale to be `en-In`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using .toLocaleString, yo just need to specify the language, optionally you can specify decimals and currency. look at this example:

```
35000.2455.toLocaleString('en-IN', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2,style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' })
```

this returns `$35,000.25`

Answer (score 0):

`Number.toLocaleString` works on a number, but `toFixed` returns a string.

Coerce the string back into a number first

```js
var number = 123.322;
var string = parseFloat(number).toFixed(2);
var parsed = (+string).toLocaleString();

console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: Could someone give me a short description of that `(+string)` ive never seen it before, im the higher end of beginner with javascript at best.

Comment: Who does javascript remove the toFixed value at the end when there is two 0's? https://jsfiddle.net/27rs5bbz/

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius - If you do `+"43"` it converts the string to a number, it would be the same as `Number("43")`, and it coerces strings. `toFixed` doesn't remove trailing zeros, but `parseFloat` does.

Comment: Thanks for that information actually, im going to give it a look over tomorrow based on what ive just learnt from you :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get commas you have to specify the locale .The locale en includes commas for the numbers. `toFixed() Returns a string`. toLocaleString() function commas works on a number not on a string.So parse the string to float.

```
var number = 1234567.322;
number = parseFloat(parseFloat(number).toFixed(2)).toFixed(2) ;
number=number.toLocaleString('en');
```

Comment: Your last line of code just a quick question, would i have to put `number = number.toLocaleString('en');` or does `number` get  assigned without the need to put the equals sign?

Comment: It depends on your locale client config.If already your client is set to en then no need to specify it. En locale gives you commas.Things that you have to notice is toLocaleString() function requires a number to get commas. So check my latest edited post.

Comment: Heres the code in action same problem: https://jsfiddle.net/s4df117w/ 
But i gave it a shot anyway

Comment: In your fiddle the problem is after converting the number to localestring you need to assign to variable number again

Comment: Please feel free to edit the fiddle if you have time, ill learn better from seeing it in action

Comment: Sorry I dont have access to fiddle now.change the line number.toLocaleString('en'); to number=number.toLocaleString('en');

Comment: This works but if the decimal is '3434.00' it removes the last two 0's at the end and returns simply '3,434', this is the main problem i have, i mentioned it in my OP but i should have made it clearer

Comment: Updated the solution check it

Comment: Wait sorry it doesnt the commas dont seem to be showing :/

Answer (score 0):

toLocaleString function provide number representation based on languages

```
 var number = 3500.00;

if(Number.isInteger(number)){

   var zeroappend= number.toLocaleString()+".00";
   console.log(zeroappend);//3,500.00;


}else{
   console.log(number.toLocaleString()); 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt answer my question

Comment: what is your expected output can you show me?@KenziieeFlavius

Comment: Clients wants it to display `3,500.00` including the 0's and all